How do I convert a virtual manifest into a package manifest?
This is almost a duplicate of existing questions about the error message below, but not quite.
I have a Cargo.toml that contains the line:
wgpu = "22.1"

and everything works just fine.  But I want to modify the library. crates.io tells me where to find this repository, and I download it to ~/github/wgpu.  I also replace the line above in in Cargo.toml to
wgpu = { path = "/users/fy/github/wgpu" }

I get the dreaded "found a virtual manifest ... instead of a package manifest".
Is there something I can put into my [dependencies] to say "You already know how to treat dependencies with virtual manifests in crates.io.  Just treat this identically?" Or is there something going on behind the scenes that I don't know about at crates.io?

You already know how to treat dependencies with virtual manifests in crates.io — actually, no, crates on crates.io always contain a regular manifest. The wgpu crate is defined in this Cargo.toml which is likely in /users/fy/github/wgpu/wgpu on your computer.

@cafce25.  Not quite sure what you're saying.  Does crates.io contain a manifest that's separate from the one on github?  I'm pointing my path at the top-level directory of what I've just pulled.

Yes and no, it's different from the root wgpu/Cargo.toml on github. It's the wgpu/wgpu/Cargo.toml in the wgpu subdirectory (I think normalized, but functionally identical to it).

Thank you. Thank you.  Thank you.  Make this into an actual answer and I'll "check" it.
